# My code repeats when I run it, is something wrong or am I able to make it run once?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to make a quick menu to where a user can have their name and change the "game's" difficulty. Except it repeats itself once you finish it. Code below

```
    print("Welcome to the menu! First we need your username!")'''

       name = input("[>: ")

       print()
       print("Thanks! Next is your difficulty. Do you want (E) Easy or (N) Normal?")'''
       print()

       difficulty = input("[>: ")

       if difficulty == "e" :
        difficulty = "Easy"
       elif difficulty == "n" :
        difficulty = "Normal"

      print()
      print("Porting you to the stats page...")
      print()

      import stats
```

And then in my stats.py file I made, I put:

```
    from main import name
    from main import difficulty

    print()
    print("Username: " + name)
    print("Difficulty: " + difficulty)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first code snippet is `main.py`.

You want to put everything from `main.py` in `if __name__ == '__main__'` to prevent `from main import name` from running `import stats` again.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Welcome to the menu! First we need your username!")'''

    name = input("[>: ")

    print()
    print("Thanks! Next is your difficulty. Do you want (E) Easy or (N) Normal?")'''
    print()

    difficulty = input("[>: ")

    if difficulty == "e" :
        difficulty = "Easy"
    elif difficulty == "n" :
        difficulty = "Normal"

    print()
    print("Porting you to the stats page...")
    print()

    import stats
```